# Xamarin Android app icon has name of launcher activity

Tags: android, xamarin.android

When our Xamarin.Android app installs and you see it in the list of all apps it has the name of the launcher activity.

In the application manifest we have android:label="AppName" and that can also be seen in the apk file manifest in the release version of the apk.

When checking in Settings in the Apps list it has the correct name.

How can I make the app having the right label in the apps list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems in Xamarin the icon name is the launcher activity's name.

If you want to use the name you set in manifest, you have to remove the Label of the `MainActivity`. Or you could just change the `label` property in `MainActivity`.